# Trying to print all the months on the x line

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I'm trying to print all the months on the x line to compare them. But it's only printing the January...

I use the [Morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) graph plugin.

```
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mar', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

  Morris.Line({ element: 'morris-line-chart', 
    data: 
      [ { month: '00', a: 100, b: 90},
        { month: '01', a: 100, b: 90 }, 
        { month: '02', a: 100, b: 90},
        { month: '03', a: 100, b: 90}, 
        { month: '04', a: 100, b: 90 },
        { month: '05', a: 100, b: 90 } ],

    xkey: 'month',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'], 
    labels: ['2015', '2014'], 
    hideHover: 'auto', 
    resize: true, 
    xLabelFormat : function (x) { return months[x.getMonth()]; }
  });
});
```

Comment: use single digit in data.month

Comment: What value you're passing in `x`? Is it `Date` object?

Comment: It seems like a basic axis label issue. Maybe a look to [**it**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rLAyLb?editors=1011) would help? (it is not closely related...)

Answer (score 2):

Update your `xLabelFormat` as below then it will work as you have expected.

```
xLabelFormat : function (x) { return months[+x.src.month] }
```

Also not that your months array has `fifth` value again `Mar`. Updated array is as below.

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
```

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [{
      month: '00',
      a: 100,
      b: 90
    },
    {
      month: '01',
      a: 100,
      b: 90
    },
    {
      month: '02',
      a: 100,
      b: 90
    },
    {
      month: '03',
      a: 100,
      b: 90
    },
    {
      month: '04',
      a: 100,
      b: 90
    },
    {
      month: '05',
      a: 100,
      b: 90
    }
  ],
  xkey: 'month',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['2015', '2014'],
  hideHover: 'auto',
  resize: true,
  xLabelFormat: function(x) {
    return months[+x.src.month]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>

<div id="bar-example"></div>
```